# grunt-contrib-sass prevent sourcemap

Tags: sass, gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-sass

My Grunt setup is using sass to compile my .scss files to src/*.css and cssmin to combine and minify my src/*.css files to main.css.

I want to use the new sourcemap feature in SASS, but I'm not sure if it will really do anything for me considering cssmin will be putting all my css files into the main.css.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

I'm also, for now trying to turn off the sourcemap in grunt-contrib-sass and it won't take. Here's the relevant code in my Gruntfile.js:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      sourcemap: 'none'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'stylesheets/scss',
      src: ['**/*.scss'],
      dest: 'stylesheets/src',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
},
```

from: [github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#sourcemap)

Comment: What version of grunt-contrib-sass are you using? You may need to upgrade. The package author answered a similar question here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/153

Comment: btw, you could use the output option with the compressed value to replace cssmin.

Answer (score 8):

I just had this problem and the other solutions didn't help me.  Here's how I fixed it:

```
options: {
  "sourcemap=none": ''
}
```

Using sass version 3.4.2, and `npm update` didn't help

Comment: ^ same here. a very ugly config option, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. As suggested in the above comment by @imjared, updating grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-contrib-sass did the trick.

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-update.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old... but the issue actually bumped me just yesterday `2023.12.31`. Sadly... `grunt-contrib-sass` no longer seems to be maintained.

By enabling `grunt --verbose` you can get a gist of what is going on in the background.

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
Files: src/sass/app.scss -> assets/css/app.min.css
Options: style="compressed", sourcemap="none"
Writing assets/css/app.css...OK
Command: sass src/sass/app.scss assets/css/app.min.css --style=compressed --sourcemap=none
Could not find an option named "sourcemap".
```

Clearly the option `sourcemap` is no longer valid...
Currently the `sass` docs want you to run it [this way](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass/#no-source-map):

```
sass --no-source-map style.scss style.css
```

I was able to coerce `grunt-contrib-sass` to disable source maps like this:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      style: 'compressed',
      'no-source-map': true,
    },
    files: {
      'assets/css/app.min.css': 'src/sass/app.scss',
    },
  },
},
```

As you can see in the `grunt --verbose` output:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
Files: src/sass/app.scss -> assets/css/app.min.css
Options: style="compressed", no-source-map
Command: sass src/sass/app.scss assets/css/app.min.css --style=compressed --no-source-map
File public/assets/css/app.min.css created
```

It's probably a short term fix... just my two cents...

Answer (score -3):

Adding sourceMap: true as below solved the problem for me (NB: I'm using grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt.sass')):

```
sass: {
  options: {
    includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss'],
    imagePath: '/images'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'nested',
      sourceMap: true
    },
    files: [{
    expand: true,
            cwd: 'scss',
    src: ['[^_]*.scss'],
    dest: '../public/css/',
    ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

Hope that helps someone.